# Web scraping with R XML package - xpathSapply

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract all the shopping mall names (e.g. CityPlaza, Fashion Walk) from this website:
https://www.discoverhongkong.com/eng/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city.html

Looking at the html code it looks like the text for the shopping malls are all stored under the tag "h5". Therefore I've used the following codes to try and extract but it doesn't give me the text I wanted.

```
url <- "https://www.discoverhongkong.com/eng/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city.html"
txt = getURL(url)
PARSED <- htmlParse(txt)
mall_text <- xpathSApply(PARSED, "//h5", xmlValue)
```

It's certainly something to do with the path I put as argument in the xpathSApply function, given I have very little knowledge about html. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The shopping mall recommendations are loaded in dynamically, so unfortunately it is not possible to obtain them in that way.
If you right-click the web-page in your browser, go to 'Inspect element', click on the 'Network' tab and refresh the page, you can see a bunch of JSON/XHR requests being made:

[image: XHR requests]

One of those urls is [this](https://www.discoverhongkong.com/eng/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city/_jcr_content/root/responsivegrid/dhkContainer/container/recommendationtiles_.recommendation-tiles.recommendationtiles_.json?path=/content/dhk/intl/en/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city). You can see it contains the information you want in JSON format.

This can easily be loaded in R using for example the `jsonlite` package.

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://www.discoverhongkong.com/eng/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city/_jcr_content/root/responsivegrid/dhkContainer/container/recommendationtiles_.recommendation-tiles.recommendationtiles_.json?path=/content/dhk/intl/en/explore/shopping/major-shopping-malls-throughout-city"
result <- read_json(url)
sapply(result$data, function(x) x$title)
```

Which gives

```
 [1] "Cityplaza"                "Fashion Walk"            
 [3] "Horizon Plaza"            "Hysan Place"             
 [5] "ifc mall"                 "Island Beverley"         
 [7] "LANDMARK"                 "Lee Garden One - Six"    
 [9] "Lee Theatre and Leighton" "Lee Tung Avenue"         
[11] "Pacific Place"            "Peak Galleria"           
[13] "SOGO Causeway Bay Store"  "Times Square"            
[15] "Western Market"           "WTC"
```

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful! How were you able to tell these shopping mall texts are loaded dynamically? Is it something stated in the html code?

Comment: The fact that you can see these texts in your browser but not in the result of `getURL(url)` means that it has to be loaded dynamically. That's the easiest way to check.